# Whats a good method to cherrypick all missing commits by an author in one branch to another

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

Say I have made a bunch of changes in master. But, I want to cherrypick all the ones not in branch:release-5 onto to it.

Comment: Why don’t you just merge master into your branch?

Comment: Don't ask ... I ask myself the same question. But, besides the point.

Comment: Just cherry-pick them all, unless memory is playing nasssty tricks on me any that are already applied will be ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cherry pick, but it would be much easier if you rebase:

```
git checkout -b missing-commits master
git rebase -i --author=me release-5
```

All the commits already in release-5 won't be picked, and only your commits will. Afterwards you can merge the branch missing-commits into release-5.

That being said you can use cherry-pick:

```
git cherry-pick --skip-empty --cherry-pick --no-merges --right-only --topo-order --do-walk master...release-5
```

As you can see it's much easier to use `git rebase`, which interally does the cherry-picking for you.

Comment: I didn't find any options for `cherry-pick --skip-empty`, is that any wrong here?

Comment: That's one option I have in my fork of Git. Unfortunately upstream Git didn't merge the patch. It just means you manually have to skip empty commits.

Comment: maybe I had found a better solution using `rev-list` to filter empty commits, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40988113/cherry-pick-set-of-commits-from-other-branch-skipping-empty-commits/40988114#40988114

Comment: Holy cow. This wins a prize. Here's a command that only works in my private git fork.

Comment: The first chunk is the one that matters. The second chunk is only to see what the first one would do, and it would work if you don't use `--skip-empty` (and there are no empty commits).

I answered the question and I explained what Git does internally, and how you could do the same **if** the Git community had applied my patch, but they didn't. I have 400 commits applied, this particular one was not. What else do you want me to do?

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of cherry-picking is that you can select a specific subset of commits you want to copy over to your branch. It exists explicitely *because* there are situations in which you don’t want to integrate all commits from another branch using merging.

Now, if you find yourself in a situation where you want to cherry-pick *all* commits that are on some other branch, then you’re exactly in the merging situation where you just want to merge that branch into your current branch to integrate all changes:

```
git checkout release-5
git merge master
```

That being said, the `A..B` revision range syntax allows you to specify commits that are reachable from `B` without those reachable from `A`. So in your case, you would want to use `release-5..master` to select all commits that are on `master` but not reachable from your `release-5` branch:

```
git cherry-pick release-5..master
```

But again, if you just want all those, merging is absolutely the better option because it won’t duplicate the commits and keep an actual history available.