# Cherry pick set of commits from other branch skipping empty commits

Tags: git

I am doing merge bunches of commits using `cherry-pick`

```
git rev-list --reverse something-begin..something-end | git cherry-pick --stdin
```

and then ends up with error message

```
...
You are currently cherry-picking commit xxxyyy.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

    git commit --allow-empty

If you wish to skip this commit, use:

    git reset

Then "git cherry-pick --continue" will resume cherry-picking the remaining commits.
```

I dont want to pick any of these empty commits.

It is very annoying that entering `git reset; git cherry-pick --continue` for each stop and prompts.

why didn't it provide a `--skip-empty` option? And then I got to this thread:

> http://markmail.org/message/yowzaetyu32ulvz7

It's so bad that I check my git version `2.9.3` and even found it `cherry-pick` do not supports either `--skip-empty` or `--empty-commpit=skip` or any other.

I had check that `git rev-list` has an option `--remove-empty` but it just did not work any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

```
git rev-list --reverse something-begin..something-end . | git cherry-pick --stdin
```

Adding a dot to `rev-list` command (that is the path parts) will skip all empty commits for me (what is `--remove-empty` for??)

Comment: As the documentation says, `--remove-empty` means "Stop when a given path disappears from the tree." That is, stop looking at earlier revisions entirely.

Comment: @torek Yes I had read that line, and I had confirmed that is not what I want. but that document line `Stop when a given path disappears from the tree` is not clear enough I just dont catch what it means.

Comment: Well, consider what `git rev-list` does if you just give it one single commit. It prints that commit's ID, and then that commit's parent's ID, and then that parent's parent ID, and then *that* parent's parent, and another and another and so on. When does it *stop* following from parent to parent? The usual answer is: when there are no more parents. But you can make it stop earlier.

Comment: Did you try `git cherry-pick something-begin..something-end` or was that not available at the time? Does it have the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use rebase in this way (having your target branch checked out):

```
git reset --hard something-end && git rebase ORIG_HEAD
```

which automatically skips redundant commits.

Credits go to my colleague [Michael Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5002783), who came up with that idea.

Comment: rebase do not work with subtree rebasing. Actually I am using cherry-pick -Xsubtree option to pick set of commits from one repository to an other witch only includes a folder of origin