# Git cherry picking a range

Tags: git, git-branch, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I have two branches that are very different from each other, however one branch contains some useful code that I would like to add to the other branch.  The branches diverged so long ago that i cannot merge them as many of their features are different and a merge is not viable.

The useful code from the donor branch was added in consecutive commits and I have the hashes of the commits I want to cherry-pick. When I give the command `git cherry-pick hash1 hash2`, I am told `nothing to commit, working tree clean. The previous cherry pick ous now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.`

Is there a way to run through all the cherry-picks allowing any commits that will produce no change to pass automatically? I would rather not sit here and have to manually continue through each empty cherry-pick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should mean, as [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7072029/6309), that all of the changes introduced by that commit have been introduced by some commit on your current branch.

First of all, double-check you have checked out first the *destination* branch, and you are not still on the source branch (the one with `hash1 hash2`)

Then, you can skip empty commits [using git rev-list as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40988114/6309):

```
git rev-list --reverse something-begin..something-end . | git cherry-pick --stdin
```

Comment: Thanks @VonC, that is exactly what I was looking for.